# django cms filer uploads fail

Tags: django, docker, django-cms, django-filer

**[Update]**

I've managed to upload a *small* file (but not yet a large image). `../media/filer_public/` sub-directories are being correctly created and file correctly uploaded. Need to investigate nginx configurations.

**[OP]**

I've logged into a new Django CMS system as superuser but cannot *Add filer image* or *Add filer file*  to a page as the file upload silently fails; very briefly flashing its upload graphics but not actually uploading anything. I believe all the `settings.py` are correct as static artifacts are rendered correctly and `Nginx` has credible similar  `locations` for both `media` and `static` directories.

I believe all file and directory permissions and ownerships are correct; i.e. that Nginx has user and / or group ownership of the Django CMS app directories and that permissions are correct.

The `Postgres` table `filer_folder` has a row for a new filer folder I created when editing a page but no corresponding directory has been created in the file system. I can add text and new text block plugins that get saved correctly.

Django CMS is running in a Docker container `web` which I have confirmed has `rw` (read/write) access to a Docker volume.

I see nothing abnormal in `web`s logs.

How can I find out what's (not) happening?

Comment: Maybe this? enctype="multipart/form-data" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/ It's a blind shot but I tried anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I think I'm narrowing down the issue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding `client_max_body_size 10M;` to the nginx configuration for the site solved the issue.

Similar issues were addressed in Stackoverflow and elsewhere:

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/514927/file-uploads-and-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-gunicorn-django)

[Setting up Django and your web server with uWSGI and nginx](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

Comment: Great answer, I've been scouring SO for a while looking for this. Most of the time people were telling me that I was missing libjpeg but I was getting zero errors stating this. Now I set this in my nginx config religiously where I will be using django-filer for larger uploads.